# XSL-FO dynamic table column width

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, multiple-columns, apache-fop

As it stands now, I have about 12 columns and all of them are exactly the same width. The problem is that some columns don't require that much space. How do I get the columns to fit their content? The columns need to be a dynamic width.

I've tried

```
<fo:table table-layout="auto">
```

And

```
<fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" column-number="1"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" column-number="2"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" column-number="3"/>
```

Nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: If you are using FOP, it won't work. FOP doesn't support `table-layout="auto"`.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea for the question itself?

Comment: Buy a commercial formatter that supports `table-layout="auto"`, such as XEP (http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html). There are also free personal and academic editions for non-commercial use: http://www.renderx.com/download/personal.html.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find a simple way to have dynamic column widths. I ended up with this:

```
<fo:table-column column-number="1"  column-width="35pt" />
<fo:table-column column-number="2"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="3"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="4"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="5"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="6"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="7"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="8"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="9"  />
<fo:table-column column-number="10" />
<fo:table-column column-number="11" />
<fo:table-column column-number="12" />
```

I specify the first column because the data will never change. The rest I leave open to fit their content. Works the way I need it to work for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify the units in "percent units". Works fine for me...

```
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="75%" /> 
<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="25%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the attribute 'proportional-column-width' for lengthy columns and remaining columns let be default.
2. Check the width of the each columns, If it is lengthy than other columns, provide how many times bigger (like 2 times or 3 times or 4.5 times or even more).

Ex-1 :

```
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(3)"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="2"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="3"/>
```

Ex-2 :

```
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="proportional-column-width(3)"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="proportional-column-width(4)"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="3"/>
```